# Shared Avro Schema files and version control

Tags: java, version-control, avro

What is the best practise for sharing an Avro schema / generated sources?

I have two Java applications that communicates through Kafka.
My thought was to use Avro schemas for the events thats flowing between the applications.
So extracting the Avro schemas into a shared library seems like a good idea. But what is actually best practice here? Normally generated files are not stored in Source Control. But is that also the case with Avro generated Java classes. If not - then each consumer will have to generate their own classes at compile time.(But is that even possible if the schemas are in a maven, gradle etc. dependency)

Answer (score 0):

Overall, version control is good, but you should ignore generated sources such as those that end up in the `target` folder in Maven.

The generated Java classes can go into a shared library placed into Nexus/Artifactory, for example during a `mvn deploy`, and from there can be appropritaely versioned for consumers to use.

Within the avro-maven-plugin generated classes, the schema is available as a static field, so you wouldn't need to copy those resources into the package.

Otherwise, assuming you are using the Confluent Schema Registry, you could use the `GenericRecord` type in your consumers, then parse the messages like you would normally for a JSON message, for example. E.g. `Object fieldName = message.value().get("fieldName")`, meanwhile producers could still have a Specific Avro class